# An exception occurred processing JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

```
message An exception occurred processing JSP page /mailbox.jsp at line 19

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /mailbox.jsp at line 19

16:         <span class="col-sm-3 title-message">Date: </span><br />
17:         <hr>
18:         <div class="col-sm-12">
19:             <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.User_messages}" var="item">
20:                 ${item}<br>
21:             </c:forEach>
22:         </div>
```

Получается такая ошибка, берется null pointer exception

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
    MessageDAO msg = new MessageOracleDAO();
    User user = new User();
    try {
        if(session.getAttribute("authUser") != null) {
            user.setEmail(session.getAttribute("authUser").toString());
            session.setAttribute("User_messages", msg.inboxMessage(user));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    req.getRequestDispatcher("mailbox.jsp").forward(req,resp);
}
```

Собственно метод.
И jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" extends="fpm.servlets.SecureJSP"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your account</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/styles.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/mail_script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="header.jsp"/>
    <jsp:include page="menu.jsp"/>
    <div class="col-sm-10 container-page">
        <span class="col-sm-3 title-message">From: </span>
        <span class="col-sm-6 title-message">Message: </span>
        <span class="col-sm-3 title-message">Date: </span><br />
        <hr>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.User_messages}" var="item">
                ${item}<br>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
        <hr>
<%--
        <div class="col-sm-12" id="42" style="display: none;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="close_form()">Х</button>
            <form action="main" method="post" class="compose form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h3 style="color: white">New Message</h3>
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="to_email">To:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="to_email" name="receiver" required maxlength="29"
                               minlength="3"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="subject">Subject:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subj" required/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="message"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <textarea style="resize: none;" class="form-control" maxlength="1000" id="message" name="msg"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
--%>
        <jsp:include page="compose.jsp"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы проверяли что возвращает `msg.inboxMessage(user)`?

Comment: Список из строк